# Error al escribir el método "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola estoy siguiendo un curso y me estanque al con un problema, sucede que al escribir ese método me lo marca en error y al darle alt + enter me salen esas opciones pero no se cual seleccionar? Según el curso me debería de aparecen una opción que me permita importar una librería pero no me aparece.

Pense que podría ser por el api en la cual esta construido en proyecto (7.1) pero hice el cambio a el 4.4 y me aparecen muchos mas errores en otras partes del código.

Agradecería si tienen alguna sugerencia a la hora de crear proyectos para evitar estos errores, apenas estoy aprendiendo todo esto así que algunas cosas todavía no las comprendo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Codigo

```
package com.example.seccion_01;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;

public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextphone;
    private EditText editTextWeb;
    private ImageButton imageButtonPhone;
    private ImageButton imageButtonCamera;
    private ImageButton imageButtonWeb;

    private final int PHONE_CALL_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        editTextphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
        editTextWeb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextWeb);
        imageButtonPhone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPhone);
        imageButtonWeb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonWeb);
        imageButtonCamera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCamera);

        imageButtonPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNumber = editTextphone.getText().toString();
                if (phoneNumber != null) {

                    //Comprobar si ha aceptado, no ha aceptado, o nunca se le ha preguntado
                    if (CheckPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                        //Ha aceptado
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ThirdActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) return;
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else {
                        // Ha denegado o es la primera vez que se le pregunta
                        if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                            //No se le ha preguntado aun
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, PHONE_CALL_CODE);
                        } else {
                            //Ha denegado
                            Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this, "Please, enable the request permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                            i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                            i.addFlags()
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }

                    //comprobar version actual de android que estamos corriendo
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                        //requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, PHONE_CALL_CODE);
                    } else {
                        OlderVersions(phoneNumber);
                    }
                }
            }

            private void OlderVersions(String phoneNumber) {
                Intent intentCALL = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
                if (CheckPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE))
                    startActivity(intentCALL);
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this, "You declined the access", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PHONE_CALL_CODE:

                String permission = permissions[0];
                int result = grantResults[0];

                if (permission.equals(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {

                    //Comprobar si ha sido aceptado o denegado la peticion de permiso
                    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        //Concedio su permiso
                        String phoneNumber = editTextphone.getText().toString();
                        Intent intentCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) return;
                        startActivity(intentCall);
                    } else {
                        //No concedio su permiso
                        Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this, "You declined the access", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean CheckPermission(String permission) {
        int result = this.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

Comment: que version de API estas usando?

Comment: Estoy usando el api 25. Android 7.1

Comment: Solo coloca el validador que Android Studio te sugiere, como estas validaciones en Runtime se comenzaron a implementar a partir de la api 23, debes especificar que solo se realizara la solicitud de ese permiso si la version de android en la que corres la app es superior a 23. De seguro tu minSdkVersion es menor a 23, por eso lo marca, Debido a que antes del api 23, solo basta con declarar los permisos en el Manifest. Pero como no es tu caso, debes especificar que ese permiso se ejecute solo para versiones superiores a 23

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías verificar el `minSdkVersion` en tu build.gradle. Android Studio te indica que deberías agregar una validación cuando la aplicación es mayor a la version M de android. Si cambias la version del `minSdkVersion` a 23 se corregirá ese error. Los permisos en Runtime solo están disponibles a partir de la version 23 en adelante, para versiones anteriores los permisos se pedirán cuando instalas la aplicación.

Referencia de la documentación : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element?hl=es-419